# Could not find Developer Disk Image iOS 9.1 & Xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9.1

When I try to run my app on my phone I get an error that reads "Could not find Developer Disk Image". At the top of Xcode it says my phone name with (Unavailable) after it.

Comment: Actually you need to use now released Xcode 7.1 to work with (also now released) iOS 9.1

Comment: You need to be using the ( now released) Xcode 7.1 in order to work with (also now released) iOS 9.1 devices.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As explained on this [Apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18282) , you need to update to Xcode 7.1 once you have updated your phone to iOS 9.1.

**UPDATE FOR iOS 9.2**

With the most recent update to iOS 9.2, the same problem will occur with Xcode at 7.1; you need to update to Xcode 7.2

It seems that Apple is forcing developers to stay up-to-date with both Xcode and iOS.  If you see "*Could not find Developer Disk Image*" in your Xcode, then your best bet to solve it is to update both your Xcode AND iOS to the most recent version.

**UPDATE FOR iOS 9.3**

It seems that Apple has thrown another monkeywrench into updating your Xcode.  Now, not only does your Xcode have to be updated, but your OSX needs to be on El Capitan. In fact, the store will not even suggest the update to Xcode 7.3 until you change the OSX.

Comment: For what it's worth, 7.1 doesn't seem to prompt you to upgrade to it if you have 7.0 installed. Or at least it didn't for me. I had to go to the OS X App Store and manually kick off the download/installation to resolve this.

Comment: They could at least leave a hint to update Xcode in the popup, because there'e plenty of room left. Also, Xcode should notify the user for updates like Android Studio does, instead of relying on App Store. In fact, Xcode should be rebuilt or just move the interface builder to AppCode and further improve AppCode, so we can abandon haXcode...

Comment: That didn't work - I updated to iOS 9.2 + xcode 7.1 and still getting this message.

Comment: @Yuvals did you figure this out? I can't deploy to physical device either even though both Xcode 7.1 and iOS 9.2 up to date

Comment: @Yuvals see my answer

Comment: It worked on updating both - keep in mind that if you don't have enough disk space it won't install Xcode update

Answer (score 2):

for iOS 9.2 and XCode 7.2

I believe this is an app store bug. Because the app store says my Xcode is update to date (7.2) but then when I go to "About" in Xcode menu it still says I'm on 7.1. I manually download Xcode 7.2 outside of Appstore and it worked

Link to manually download 7.2
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: This should have more upvotes!

Sadly the Xcode 7.2 is not a patch but the Xcode suite with its glorious 4.4 GB file size. *sigh*